# Web.config session-state code error

Tags: web-config, session-state

Firstly, I executed the installsqlstate.sql on to my server and then I wrote sessionstate code.

```
<sessionState  mode="SQLServer"  sqlConnectionString="data source=idealserver;user id=sa;password=**"  cookieless="false" timeout="20" allowCustomSqlDatabase="true"/>
```

Then I run my web project, it did not work and it returned an error like

> Unable to use SQL Server because ASP.NET version 2.0 Session State is not installed on the SQL server. Please install ASP.NET Session State SQL Server version 2.0 or above.

I don't understand the warning and I don't know how I will continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you may have installed the wrong version. Try running installsqlstate.sql located at 
*system drive*\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\version\v2.0.50727